# C++ input output

Tags: c++, c++11

I saw two codes and was wondering why one should work and the other not....thanks in advance..

I know it's a really simple question but thanks for your time

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <cstring>
const int STR_LIM = 50;
int main()
{

char word[STR_LIM];
cout << "Enter word, to stop; press the word done" << endl;
int Count = 0;

while (cin >> word && strcmp("done", word))
    ++ Count;
cout << "You entered a total of " << Count << " words. \n";


return 0;
}
```

And:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int i = 0;
char word[256];

while(cin >> word != "done")
    ++i;

cout << i;

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by “work”? Please provide the expected and actual behaviour.

Comment: I dont think cin >> word can be directly compared with the string "done" like you have done in the 2nd example. what you have done in the 1st example - by actually reading the input and using strcmp seems to be the right approach.

Answer (score 0):

Becuase `cin>>word` returns ostream object and it is not comparable with Strings!

Answer (score 0):

Why does

```
while(cin >> word != "done") ++i;
```

not work?

At first, the operator precedences have to be checked e.g. [C++ Operator Precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) to find the order of evaluation. So, `>>` binds stronger than `!=`. Hence, the above code is identical with

```
while((cin >> word) != "done") ++i;
```

Next, the types of operators/expressions have to be analyzed:

`(cin >> word)` is `std::istream&` × `char*` → `std::istream&`

according to e.g. [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt).

Hence,

`((cin >> word) != "done")` is `std::istream&` × `const char[5]`

which may decay to `std::istream&` × `const char*`.

There is no `bool operator!=(std::istream&, const char*)` available.

Hence, it does not compile.

Life demo on [**ideone**](https://ideone.com/RVQgbq)

```
prog.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
prog.cpp:10:25: error: no match for ‘operator!=’ (operand types are ‘std::basic_istream<char>’ and ‘const char [5]’)
       while(cin >> word != "done")  ++i;
             ~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~
```

---

Without the abbreviation it should:

```
while(cin >> word && strcmp(word, "done")) ++i;
```

Using `std::string word;` instead of `char word[256];` it can be written even more intuitive as

```
while(cin >> word && word != "done") ++i;
```

because `std::string` provides suitable `operator!=()`s for this.

Life demo on [**ideone**](https://ideone.com/sVodQc).